# How to clear DataTable with onchange in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have used fnDestroy() to clear the dataTable on change of a select element, but it doesn't clear the table, instead it appends the data into the table. Here's the code.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <select class="form-control" id="changeView">
        <option value="1">All</option>
        <option value="2">Compiled</option>
        <option value="3">On-Going</option>
        <option value="4">Cancelled</option>
    </select>
</div>

<table class="table table-condensed" id="documentsTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>From</th>
           <th>Status</th>
           <th>Subject</th>
           <th>Date Received</th>
           <th>Due Date</th>
           <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#changeView').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var change = '';
    if (value === '1') {
        change = 'All';
    } else if (value === '2') {
        change = 'Compiled';
    } else if (value === '3') {
        change = 'On-Going';
    } else if (value === '4') {
        change = 'Cancelled';
    }

    loadDocuments(change);
});

function loadDocuments(change) {
    $('#documentsTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();

    $.post(base_url + "admin/document/getAllDocuments", {change: change}, function(response, status) {
        var result = JSON.parse(response);

        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            var dateReceived = format_mysqldate(field['dateReceived']);
            var dueDate = format_mysqldate(field['dueDate']);

            $('#documentsTable tbody').append('<tr><td>' + field['from'] + '</td><td>' + field['status'] + '</td><td>' + field['subject'] + '</td><td>' + dateReceived + '</td><td>' + dueDate +
                    '</td><td><div class="visible-md visible-lg visible-sm visible-xs btn-group">' +
                    '<a href="' + base_url + 'admin/document/view/' + field['id'] + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="View Details" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>' +
                    '<a href="' + base_url + 'admin/document/edit/' + field['id'] + '" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" title="Edit Document" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>' +
                    '</div></td></tr>');
        });
        $('#documentsTable').dataTable({
            "aoColumns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                {"bSortable": false}
            ],
            "order": [[3, "desc"]],
            "bDestroy": true
        });
    });
}
```

Can any one tell me what is wrong with my code? I can't get to clear the dataTable in every change of selection.
Thank you ahead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may try to clear the datatable first and then destroy it.

```
dataTable.fnClearTable();
dataTable.fnDraw();
dataTable.fnDestroy();
```

Comment: You've nailed it. Thanks. :)

Comment: This is good for dataTable version **1.9** *(for a legacy code base I'm maintaining)*

Comment: You are a saviour. Thanks.

Comment: you nailed it, working like a charm, thanks a lot @Kursad Gulseven

Answer (score 16):

Clear and destroy methods could be called like this,

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

//clear datatable
table.clear().draw();

//destroy datatable
table.destroy();
```

Reference;

- [Clear](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy%28%29) API method
- [Destroy](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear%28%29) method

*Note: This code will work for datatable version 1.10 and above.*

Comment: does not work at v.1.10.20 and v.1.11.3

Comment: Works with 1.13.6.

Answer (score 4):

It could be destroy() http://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy(). Then empty the tbody.

```
$('#documentsTable').dataTable().destroy();
$('#documentsTable tbody').empty();
```

Comment: It gives an error that says "destroy() is not a function". But the answer above solved my problem. Thanks any way. :)

Comment: $('#documentsTable tbody').empty(); This solved my problem... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code to clear and destroy datatable

```
    $('#example1').dataTable().fnClearTable();
    $('#example1').dataTable().fnDraw();
    $('#example1').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```